# How to test login based on Keycloak test using JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, keycloak

We have an app that has a keycloak login. I want to create a JMeter test that logs in using some credential than do some stuff. the problem is I don't know how to form the POST URL

https://something.something.something.something/auth/realms/test/login-actions/authenticate?session_code=D3XPlFteuLSReLVsPbmCYY8RwqJDPmxb9JI1dBtR1yk&execution=021d7cc9-048c-4f68-a295-6d145597dd8e&client_id=my-react-client&tab_id=ACD97a5Yb50”

How to get the other parameters for the Post URL inside the test. They are not in the previous HTTP response (accessing the login page) and there are not in the cookies. I know how to get only the ***client_id***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keycloak supports [2 authentication protocols](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#supported-protocols):

1. [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/connect/)
2. [SAML 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAML_2.0)

Looking into your URL it's utterly like that your Keycloak instance is using OpenID and looking into [OpenID Configuration Options](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/#configuration-options)

> ```
> client-id: <CLIENT_ID>
>
> # the secret associated to the 'client' application
> ```

So my expectation is that this is something which doesn't change so feel free to keep it as `my-react-client`

Just in case get familiarized with [OpenID Connect - How to Load Test with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/openid-connect-how-to-load-test-with-jmeter) to learn more about the concept of bypassing login challenge in JMeter tests when it comes to external authentication providers.